# Dynamically create objects in Typescript using dynamic keys, without widening type to { [key: string]: T }

Tags: typescript, mapped-types

#### Dynamic object key without widening to `{ [key: string]: V }` ?

I'm trying to create a Typescript function to **generate an object with a dynamic key whose name is provided in the function signature, without the return type getting widened to `{ [key: string]: V }`**.

So I want to call:

`createObject('template', { items: [1, 2, 3] })`

and get back an object `{ template: { items: [1, 2, 3] } }` that isn't just an object with string keys.

#### Quick detour - Lets make a rainbow!

Before you tell me this is impossible, let's make a rainbow:

```
type Color = 'red' | 'orange' | 'yellow';
 
const color1: Color = 'red';
const color2: Color = 'orange';
```

Create two [dynamic properties](https://www.samanthaming.com/tidbits/37-dynamic-property-name-with-es6/) on a rainbow object:

```
const rainbow = {
    [color1]: { description: 'First color in rainbow' },
    [color2]: { description: 'Second color in rainbow' }
};
```

Now let's look at the **type** of what we created:

```
 type rainbowType = typeof rainbow;
```

The compiler is smart enough to know that the first property must be named `'red'` and the second is called `'orange'`, giving the following **type**. This enables us to use autocomplete for any object typed as `typeof rainbow`:

```
type rainbowType = {
    red: {
        description: string;
    };
    orange: {
        description: string;
    };
}
```

Thanks Typescript!

So now we've confirmed we can create an object with dynamic properties and it won't **always** end up typed as `{ [key: string]: V }`. Of course putting this into a method is going to complicate things...

#### First attempt

So now for the first attempt to create our method and see if we can trick the compiler into giving the right result.

```
function createObject<K extends 'item' | 'type' | 'template', T>(keyName: K, details: T)
{
    return {
        [keyName]: details
    };
}
```

This is a function to which I'll provide a **dynamic key name** (constrained to one of three choices) and assign a value to it.

```
const templateObject = createObject('template', { something: true });
```

This will return an object with a runtime **value** of `{ template: { something: true } }`.

Unfortunately the type of this has been widened as you may have feared:

```
typeof templateObject = {
    [x: string]: {
        something: boolean;
    };
}
```

#### Solution using conditional types

Now there *is* an easy way to fix this if you only have a few possible key names:

```
function createObject<K extends 'item' | 'type' | 'template', T extends {}>(keyName: K, details: T)
{
    const newObject: K extends 'item' ? { item: T } :
                     K extends 'type' ? { type: T } :
                     K extends 'template' ? { template: T } : never = <any>{ [keyName]: details };

    return newObject;
}
```

This uses a [**conditional type**](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/conditional-types.html) to force the return type to have an explicitly named key the same as the value passed in.

If I call `createObject('item', { color: 'red' })` I'll get back an object with a **type** of:

```
{
    item: {
        color: string;
    };
}
```

This strategy requires that you update your method if you need a new key name, which isn't always going to work.

That's often where this discussion would end!

#### What about fancy newer Typescript features?

I'm not satisfied with that and wanted to do better. So I wondered if any of the newer Typescript language features like [**Template literals**](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/template-literal-types.html) might help.

You can do some really clever things like the following (this is just a random fun unrelated example):

```
type Animal = 'dog' | 'cat' | 'mouse';
type AnimalColor = 'brown' | 'white' | 'black';

function createAnimal<A extends Animal, 
                      C extends AnimalColor>(animal: A, color: C): `${C}-${A}`
{
    return <any> (color + '-' + animal);
}
```

The magic here is the template literal `${C}-${A}`. So let's create an animal...

```
const brownDog = createAnimal('dog', 'brown');;

// the type brownDogType is actually 'brown-dog' !!
type brownDogType = typeof brownDog;
```

Unfortunately, here you're effectively just creating a 'smarter string type'.

I tried really hard, but couldn't get any further using template literals.

#### What about [**Key Remapping via `as`**](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/mapped-types.html#key-remapping-via-as)...

Could I maybe remap a key and get the compiler to retain that new key name in the returned type.....

##### It turns out it works, but it's sort of awful:

Key remapping only works with a **mapped type** and I don't have a mapped type. But maybe I could make one. How about taking a dummy type with only one key, and mapping that?

```
type DummyTypeWithOneKey = { _dummyProperty: any };

// this is what we want the key name to be (note: it's a type, not a string)
type KEY_TYPE = 'template';

// Now we use the key remapping feature
type MappedType = { [K in DummyTypeWithOneKey as `${ KEY_TYPE }`]: any };
```

The magic here is `as` ${ KEY_TYPE }` which changes the name of the key.

The compiler now tells us that:

```
type MappedType = {
    template: any;
}
```

This type **can** be returned from a function and not get converted into a stupid string indexed object.

#### Meet StrongKey<K, V>

So now what? I can create a helper type to abstract away the horrible dummy type.

Note that autocomplete suggests `_dummyProperty` so I've renamed it to `dynamicKey`.

```
export type StrongKey<K extends string, V> = { [P in keyof { dynamicKey: any } as `${ K }`]: V };

function createObject<K extends 'item' | 'type' | 'template', T extends {}>(keyName: K, details: T)
{
    return { [keyName]: details } as StrongKey<K, T>;
}
```

If I now do the following I'll finally get autocomplete for obj!!!

```
const obj = createObject('type', { something: true });
```

#### What if I want to use string?

Turns out we can take it one step further and change the key type/name to be a pure string and everything still works!

```
export type StrongKey<K extends string, V> = { [P in keyof { dynamicKey: any } as `${ K }`]: V };

// creates a 'wrapped' object using a well known key name
function createObject<K extends string, T extends {}>(keyName: K, details: T)
{
    return { [keyName]: details } as StrongKey<K, T>;
}
```

#### Combine generated objects

If we can't combine the generated objects then everything is in vain. Fortunately the following works:

```
const dynamicObject = {...createObject('colors', { colorTable: ['red', 'orange', 'yellow' ] }),
                       ...createObject('animals', { animalTable: ['dog', 'cat', 'mouse' ] }) };
```

And `typeof dynamicObject` becomes

```
{
    animals: {
        animalTable: string[];
    };
    colors: {
        colorTable: string[];
    };
}
```

So sometimes Typescript is cleverer than it thinks it is.

What's my actual question? Is this the best we will ever be able to do? Should I file an issue with a suggestion? Did I miss anything? Did you learn anything? Am I the first person to ever do this?

Comment: Yo this is some question. I had to scroll down just to see if it ends. Ok scrolling back up now

Comment: @smac89 Kept me up way too late last night - wanted to get it all written down for input. Wasn't able to find any other solution to this problem but found many similar questions.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can make [mapped types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/mapped-types.html) iterate over any key or union of keys you want without having to resort to remapping-with-`as`.  Mapped types don't need to look like `[P in keyof T]`... they can be `[P in K]` for any keylike `K`.  The canonical example of this is [the `Record<K, T>` utility type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#recordkeystype) whose [definition](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/blob/15b4b32b39d71680aeb5a07a9e03417ad4eb124d/lib/lib.es5.d.ts#L1496-L1501) looks like this:

```
type Record<K extends keyof any, T> = {
    [P in K]: T;
};
```

and represents an object type whose keys are of type `K` and whose values are of type `T`.  This is essentially what your `StrongKey<K, T>` is doing without passing through the dummy middleman of `keyof { dynamicKey: any }`.

---

So your `createObject()` function could be written as:

```
function createObject<K extends string, T extends {}>(keyName: K, details: T) {
  return { [keyName]: details } as Record<K, T>;
}
```

Which produces the same output:

```
const dynamicObject = {
  ...createObject('colors', { colorTable: ['red', 'orange', 'yellow'] }),
  ...createObject('animals', { animalTable: ['dog', 'cat', 'mouse'] })
};

/* const dynamicObject: {
    animals: {
        animalTable: string[];
    };
    colors: {
        colorTable: string[];
    };
} */
```

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABBATgUwIZTQeQEYBWa0APANKJoAe2YAJgM6INQoxgDmANIgCqU009JgG8AvgD4AFAGs0ATwByGALZoAXIjI86aKBhgAbBpt4BKRCIBQiROiggUSEYgDacparQBdTbv1GTGKIGEwASsRwKHTkPLwSANxWYlZWEAgsiHTyYKowEPhE0IgAvJY2iAB01aiY2IXEUFIA5OmGUQzNPC5tUbwYeIYabs3odF2IzVEYnGgTzfJohu0A7s3eiGJmXBXVlbVYuISNLTMwKhjGEy5nF4b9g8OuzXRwHPMQWPMqcCAMcxstskklYAPQAKmQGSgWRyeQKx2gmmstlst0uJnKqOxITA50uDyGmhYbE4rm8SWxYkpqN6KExKJxtjphOGJPYHHJNNs1OSiHBoKsQA)