# Typescript generic function that returns key of union parameter

Tags: typescript, generics

I would like to write a function that returns an object, whose key is based on the parameter. I would like this to be statically typed, and I think it should be possible as the value is present at transpile time. Here is the example:

```
type ResponseKeys = 'a' | 'b';

interface A {
    city: string;
}

interface B {
    town: string;
}

interface Result<T> {
    data: T | null;
}

function transform<T>(operationName: ResponseKeys): { [operationName in ResponseKeys]?: Result<T> } {
    return {
        [operationName]: {
            data: null,
        },
    };
}

console.log(transform<A>('a'));
```

[Try it out on Typescript playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAShDOYD2A7eEDSETygXigHIBDQqAHyICNCBuAKHoEsVgIAnAM2IGNoBBKAG96UMVB5NQALijxg7FgHMGAX0Ys2XXtABCw0eOBIA7ilnzFKFfXXNWHbn1gIArgBtgAHgAqAPgNxKAATYmBiWR8KKBQPdzVGTlcUHmAmVCgFYjROJHYAW18-AAokSHYw9JQAOWJ8iFk4RFR0LBwASlkhKABtMo5K1Fr6qBYXZrRMbHgAXQB+RrdPIqhVQPF2CGBXdhR1oLE+8sGauogZrsMDg9Dw2Vj3dwAaK4PVF6DVBPoeFqR3CAAOncSCUxSyOTyhX4JRIhHa7VoQA)

I get the function response I want, but the type signature for `transform()` is:

```
{
    a?: Response<A> | undefined;
    b?: Response<A> | undefined;
}
```

I am hoping to narrow and better define it to:

```
{
    a: Response<A>;
}
```

i.e. with only the specified key, and without it being a union with undefined.

Comment: Does [this approach](https://tsplay.dev/WJA7vm) meet your needs?  If so I will write up an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two different issues:

1. You need a binding between response key ('a') and transform result (A).
2. Typescript doesn't play well with computed properties in such cases (see https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/41779)

One solution is to handle both issues by overload signatures:

```
function transform(operationName: 'a') : {a: Result<A>};
function transform(operationName: 'b') : {b: Result<B>};

function transform<T>(operationName: ResponseKeys) : {[key: string]: Result<T>} {
    if (operationName === "a") {
        return {a: {data: null}};
    } else {
        return {b: {data: null}};
    }
}

const resultA: {a: Result<A>} = transform('a');
const resultB: {b: Result<B>} = transform('b');
```

Another way is to provide explicit binding for #1 and force #2 by type assertion:

```
type TransformType<K extends ResponseKeys> = {a: A, b: B}[K];
type ResponseResult<K extends ResponseKeys> = Record<K, Result<TransformType<K>>>;

function transform<K extends ResponseKeys>(operationName: K) : ResponseResult<K> {
    return {[operationName] : {data: null}} as ResponseResult<K>;
}

const resA: ResponseResult<'a'> = transform('a');
const resB: ResponseResult<'b'> = transform('b');
```

Comment: Also there is a very similar question posted just after yours:
https://stackoverflow.com/q/75475892/2892277

Comment: Worth to mention: https://stackoverflow.com/a/68092471