# use a parameter value for inference

Tags: typescript, type-inference

```js
class Foo1 {
  a: number = 42
}

class Foo2 {
  a: string = "foobar"
}

type Format = "foo1" | "foo2"

function foo(format: Format) {
  if (format === "foo1") return new Foo1();
  return new Foo2()
}

const f = foo("foo1");
```

Here, f is inferred as a `Foo1` or a `Foo2`, even if I know that it's strictly a `Foo1`.

Is it possible to write some generics annotations in `foo` to help it infer the return type?

Comment: Please consider removing the update and posting [your own answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer) directly.

Answer (score 4):

You probably want overloads here where you have a function signature for each option, and the return type of that option explicitly set.

```
function foo(format: 'foo1'): Foo1
function foo(format: 'foo2'): Foo2
function foo(format: Format) {
  if (format === "foo1") return new Foo1();
  return new Foo2()
}

const f = foo("foo1"); // Foo1
```

[See Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?jsx=0#code/MYGwhgzhAEBiD28CM0DeAoa0wC5oDsBXAWwCMBTAJ2gF5oAWAJnQF911RIYF5G1NseCABdKAS3wBzWtABEAM0SkwlWa3bCAngAdyceJWJhhMhYiSzoAHzmLea9PML5gwsfHzQ7ACkWHjeADkdkiBAJR4PEiOzq7unj5+RsJBdozhkYjMTi5uHl6IvgbJmf7CYfxYYvLQRWW0NHRmyLIVlOTChJSe+OQA7vrI3mEA3ALtnd0E-YOMw+ocHiJeMj7NFqNAA)

Answer (score 0):

My bad, it's not that hard:

```js
function foo(format: "foo1") : Foo1;
function foo(format: "foo2") : Foo2;
function foo(format : Format) {
  if (format === "foo1") return new Foo1();
  return new Foo2()
}
```

Note that if I want that types work with something that is a `Format` (so either "foo1" or "foo2", for instance a variable), I have to add another override signature:

```js
function foo(format: Format) : Foo1 | Foo2;
```